# How can I evaluate a power operation to output a number with "e" using python?

Tags: python, math

I want to output the result of a power operation, for example:

```
100**100
```

However instead of outputting:

```
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I want it to output a result which includes "e" in it:

```
1e+200
```

I have looked on other similar Stack Overflow questions, but I couldn't find a way for me to do this without defining another function for this.

Is there an inbuilt Python function to do this?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it is my mistake for not adding more detail in my question. I have done so now, but I was looking for a way to do this without having to define a new function to do this.

Comment: The `e` in scientific notation refers to exponent, not Euler's Number which is e = 2.7182818284590452353602874713527........

Comment: Thank you I have fixed that in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If its just about printing then use this -

```
e = 100**100
"{:.2e}".format(e)
```

```
'1.00e+200'
```

Answer (score 3):

use `str.format()` to print a number in scientific notation, use `"{:e}"` as `str` to format the number in scientific notation.

```
number = 12300000
value = "{:.2e}".format(number)

print(value)
```

output : `1.23e+07`